# OpenCV, passing Mat by reference, and change it type

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, image-processing

I came up with that code, for rotate images without cropping them.
It just change che size of the destination image, in order to avoid corners to be cutted out:

Actual `rotate.cpp` code:

```
    int diagonal = (int)sqrt(src.cols*src.cols+src.rows*src.rows);
    int newWidth = diagonal;
    int newHeight = diagonal;
    cv::Mat container = cv::Mat::zeros(newWidth, newHeight, src.type());
    int offsetX = (newWidth - src.cols) / 2;
    int offsetY = (newHeight - src.rows) / 2;

    src.copyTo(container.rowRange(offsetY, offsetY + src.rows).colRange(offsetX, offsetX + src.cols));

    dst = container.clone();

    float rads = angle*3.1415926/180.0;
    float _cos = cos(-rads);
    float _sin = sin(-rads);
    float xcenter = (float)(container.cols)/2.0;
    float ycenter = (float)(container.rows)/2.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < container.rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < container.cols; j++){

            int x = ycenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_cos - ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_sin;
            int y = xcenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_sin + ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_cos;

            if (x >= 0 && x < container.rows && y >= 0 && y < container.cols) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                    dst.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[k] = container.at<cv::Vec4b>(x, y)[k];
                  }

            else {
                dst.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[3] = 0;
            }
        }

    cv::imshow("dst", dst);
```

The `imshow` function at the end is just for check the result, and as per this screenshot(ignore color differences, Qt reads in `RGBA`, `imshow` in `BGR`):

[image: Screen]

As you can see, the Label inside my application, doesn't seems to be affected, the `imshow` run from the `updateUi` function same as label (`updateUi` is launched whenever the `observer` is notified from the `model`), and the `imshow` launched from inside the `Rotation` function is correctly displaying the rotated image.

Now, before reaching that point, my algorithm was:

```
    float rads = angle*3.1415926/180.0;
    float _cos = cos(-rads);
    float _sin = sin(-rads);
    float xcenter = (float)(src.cols)/2.0;
    float ycenter = (float)(src.rows)/

    for(int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++){

            int x = ycenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_cos - ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_sin;
            int y = xcenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*_sin + ((float)(j)-xcenter)*_cos;
            if (x >= 0 && x < src.rows && y >= 0 && y < src.cols) {
                    dst.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j) = src.at<cv::Vec4b>(x, y);
                  }
            else {
                dst.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[3] = 0;
            }
```

and it was perfectly showing on my Qt Label (apart of course, the corners).
Now, my thought is that there's something strange going on in the

```
...code...
dst = container.clone();
...code...
```

I tried already different changes, like using another Mat obj, and at the end making

```
rotatedMat.copyTo(dst);
or...
dst = rotatedMat.clone();
```

but it still seems that my `dst` Mat, is not changing in the Model.
Of course, I'm passing my `src` and `dst` by reference to all my function.

Comment: @user8190410 that's what it seems, but it's not (unfortunately), problem seems to be related to 'dst' copy functions. Don't know, maybe sloning a bigger Mat in a smaller is a problem for opencv? (I'm sure is not the notify() function from the observers, as with the other similar code everything is correctly working, apart corners of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests, seems that every resize/clone/copy function on Mat objs, deallocate the memory before clone/copy.../...That's why reference to DST was not effective.
Workaround: just resize the dst matrix outside the function call.